# Rewriting a limit of the cumulative density function

Tags: limits, probability-theory

In the expression of the probabibility of a single point

$P(X=a)=P(\{a\})$=$$\lim_{\epsilon \to \ 0^+}P(a- \epsilon<X\leq a)=$$

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to \ 0^+}(F_X(a)-F_X(a- \epsilon))$$

Can I express this limit as the left side limit of $F_X$ as $x$ approaches $a$ from the left?

$$\lim_{\ x \to \ a^-}(F_X(a)-F_X(x))$$.

Comment: $X \to a^{-}$ has no meaning.

Comment: Why not? I want to denote that the cdf approaches the point $a$ from the left.

Comment: The convention in probability theory is that capital letters $X$ denote a random variable, i.e. a function of the sample space: $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, while lower-case letters, $x$, denote real numbers, a value that the random variable may or may not take on. So $X \to a$ is ill-defined, while $x\to a$ is, technically.

Comment: I will edit it.Thanks

Comment: @NapD.Lover If I write $\lim_{\ X \to \ a^-}$, I'm denoting that the random varible $X$ approaches $a$ from the left.  You are also mixing capital $X$ and real numbers when you write $P(a<X<b)$.

Comment: @ronjacobs wikipedia agrees with the notation I’m using, so do many excellent probability texts (Probability with Martingales by D. Williams for example). See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution under continuous distributions.

Comment: @ronjacobs In order for $X(\omega)$ to approach a real $a$ (from whatever direction), one needs a notion of metric or topology on $\Omega$ which is almost never explicitly given. Remember the cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$ is *defined* as $F_X(x):=P(X \leq x)$ *for all reals* $x$. Perhaps you should post another question if after perusing wikipedia you still feel confused or that Kabo and I are incorrect.

Comment: Last comment: if it’s not clear, I do not mean to insist *any expression combining RVs* $X$ *and reals* $x$ is ill-defined, only certain ones for example like $X\to a$ which implicitly depends on the topology of $\Omega$.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Not at all I'm saying that you and Kabo are incorrect. It is just that I'd like to understand why $X \to a^{-}$ has no meaning. Could you explain in lay terms what you mean when you say that "$X \to a$ which implicitly depends on the topology of Ω"

Comment: @ronjacobs certainly, I am terribly sorry if it was too much jargon! Technically speaking random variables are functions, as I said before, so analogously when we write for some function $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$ where $D$ is some subset of the reals, $f(t)\to a$, we always talk about the input approaching a point as well: we write $f(t)\to a$ as $t\to c$. For real numbers, we have a notion of limits, so we can always talk about this limiting procedure. For a random variable $X: \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ the domain $\Omega$ is an abstract set: we don’t necessarily have a notion of limit $\omega \to c$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can write it in that form. The first term $F_X(a)$ niether depends on $\epsilon$ nor on $x$. So what you are asking is whether $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} F_X(a-\epsilon)=\lim_{x \to a-} F_X(x)$$ which is true.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a little confused with the notation, when you write $P(a<X<b)$ you use capital letter X, but $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

Comment: $P(a<X<b)$ is the probability that the random variable $X$ takes values (strictly) between $a$ and $b$. If you replace $X$ by $x$ you get probability of something that is not even a random event.